# Is there a way to store a variable in an Applescript Library?

Tags: applescript

So I have a variable that I use in almost every script, which is hard to remember.

I can save it in a custom library as a function, but I want it as a variable.

So for example:

In Script Library "Math":

```applescript
property infinity: 10 ^ 308.254715 -- biggest possible Number

on infinity()
    return 10 ^ 308.254715 -- biggest possible Number
end infinity
```

In a normal script:

```applescript
tell script "Math"
    return infinity -- Produces error about how infinity isn't defined
    return infinity() -- Works
end tell
```

Is it possible to save it as a variable or am I forced to save it as a function?

Comment: @user3439894 Could you write that as an answer?

Comment: FWIW, assuming the above isn't shorthand, I think your definition of infinity is incorrect. Should be 1.797693 × 10^308 (per 'Real', p118 in ASLG).

Comment: @Mockman Thanks for making me aware of that, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *script* **Math** having:

```applescript
property infinity: 10 ^ 308.254715
```

Then in a *script* other than *script* **Math**, you can do the following:

```applescript
property infinity : infinity of script "Math"
```

Then use `infinity` however you'd like as if `property infinity: 10 ^ 308.254715` was in the *script*.

Example: `return infinity`

Comment: Is there a way to set those variables so they cannot be changed or is it actually impossible to define your own constants?

Comment: @gurkensaas, RE: "Is there a way to set those variables so they cannot be changed or is it actually impossible to define your own constants?" -- Not trying to be flip but I'd have to say a _variable_ that cannot be changed is not a  _variable_. As to being able to define your own _constant_, that sound like a good topic for another question that I do not have a direct answer for, sorry. Maybe creating your own **AppleScript** _dictionary_, a **.sdef** _file_, although I'm not sure of it, but though I'd mention it.

Comment: According to the [offictial Applescript documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCECDHC), "You cannot define constants in scripts; constants can be defined only by applications and by AppleScript." That probably means no if I don't want to go through the hassle of writing my own .sdef file.