# Is there a way to have constants in Applescript?

Tags: constants, applescript

I'm currently working on an Applescript math library, which mimics the python `math` module. The python `math` module has some constants, such as [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) and others. Currently, you can do something like this:

```applescript
set math to script "Math"

log math's E -- logs (*2.718281828459*)

set math's E to 10

log math's E -- logs (*10*)
```

So I tried searching for Applescript constants and came across [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCECDHC), where it is stated, that `You cannot define constants in scripts; constants can be defined only by applications and by AppleScript.`

Is there a clever workaround for this or would I have to write a .sdef file for this sort of thing?

#### EDIT:

I have now also tried this:

```applescript
log pi -- logs (*3.14159265359*)

set pi to 10

log pi -- logs (*10*)
```

`pi` is an Applescript constant. If you run the script a second time without compiling again, it looks something like this:

```applescript
log pi -- logs (*10*)

set pi to 10

log pi -- logs (*10*)
```

I don't want to mimic this behavior, but more so the behavior of other constants like `ask`, `yes`, `no`, etc. which complain, even if you try to set them to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to explicitly define a constant in AppleScript. There are three approaches that might suffice, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

---

If you're using a Scripting Definition (sdef) in your library, you can add an enumeration to define terms you want to reserve, then handle them by cases in code. For instance, if you want to assign constant values to the terms 'tau', 'gamma', and 'lambda', you define an enumeration like so:

```
<enumeration name="Constants" code="CVal" description="defined constant values.">
    <enumerator name="tau" code="tau&" description="tau constant."/>
    <enumerator name="gamma" code="gam&" description="gamma constant."/>
    <enumerator name="lambda" code="lmd!" description="lambda constant."/>
</enumeration>
```

Then in code have a handler to resolve them, and call it when needed:

```
to resolveConstant(cnst)
    if cnst is tau then
        return pi/2
    else if cnst is gamma then 
        return 17.4683
    else if cnst is lambda then 
        return "wallabies forever"
    else
        return missing value
    end
end resolveConstant
```

---

Create handlers for each of your constants, and call them as functions:

```
on tau()
    return pi/2
end tau

set x to 2 * tau() * 3^2 -- x = 28.2743
```

---

If you want *true* constants, you're going to have to shift away from a script library and code a faceless background app (like System Events or Image Events). From the perspective of an end-user it won't make much difference, save that they'll have to authorize having the application run, but it might mean a serious increase in labor on your end.

Comment: Your first approach sounds the best to me, how would I go about implementing a scripting definition into a library? Do I need to store it as a bundle?

Comment: @gurkensaas: Start with this [MacOSXAutomation article on script libraries](https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/libraries/index.html), and work or jump through to the page called 'Libraries with Terminology'. Yes, it has to be a script bundle (so you have someplace to put the sdef file), but the instructions are pretty straightforward.

Comment: I have followed the video they posted on MacOSXAutomation up until the `Creating a Bundle step` and then then I tried to compile the bundle. The error message says that [my dictionary](https://pastebin.com/H2Jcw1Vm) is corrupted. I have no idea why, could you take a look at it or should I post a new question?

Comment: @gurkensaas: the sdef looks fine to me: I don't see any of the common plist errors (dropped angle brackets, missing quotation marks, absent or misplaced closing tags, etc. Did you use a plain-text editor (like BBEDit) to make the file? Sometimes people use rich text editors or word processors, which through in weird white-space characters that can't be seen but can't be processed by Script Editor. Note that TextEdit has both rich-text and plain-text modes, and you have to make sure you're not in RT.

Comment: I used VSCode in XML Mode which shouldn't cause any whitespace characters. The file can also be opened in the Script Editor and displays information in a normal way.

Comment: @gurkensaas: you can also validate the sdef file in terminal using the xmllint utility (xmllint --noout --postvalid --xinclude YourApp.sdef). see [Cocoa Scripting Guide](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/cocoa-scripting-guide.pdff) page 105.

Comment: Should there be any output when running this in the Terminal?

Comment: @gurkensaas: Meh. Hate to say it, but sometimes you need to close the applescript bundle you're working with and reopen it in Script Editor (or just quit and restart SE). SE caches a lot of information about scriptability, and there's no button to press to make it clear the cache and reload.

Comment: @gurkensaas: I think if the sdef is valid it won't produce an output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237842/discussion-between-gurkensaas-and-ted-wrigley).

Answer (score 0):

Every handler name with parameters is constant in the AppleScript. You can use this fact. Here, you can't change the name of the  handler, so you can consider it like your constant pi identifier. It is true constant because you can't set it, but you can get it whatever you want:

```
on constantPi()
    3.14159265359
end constantPi

get constantPi() --> 3.14159265359
set constantPi() to 10 --> Access not allowed
```

Note: do not remove parentheses in the last code line, otherways you create additional variable constantPi instead of your "constant"

Comment: The parentheses seem very unnatural. I want the end-user to have the best experience. I do not need a reminder that I can't change a variable, but I plan on distributing the code. I of course knew about your approach.

Comment: Please look at [my question before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69419590/is-there-a-way-to-store-a-variable-in-an-applescript-library) and tell me I didn't know about that.